# why does udev create device nodes?

Tags: linux, udev

so i understand why device nodes need to exist, but why does udev make them?

can someone explain to me the relationship between udev and device nodes?

how does udev make device nodes? why does udev make device nodes?

does any other program make device nodes, if not why?

where do device nodes go? do they all stay in one place?

i don't know how else to articulate this question so i'm writing this because it won't let me post the question with out more letters,

thank you

Comment: "why does udev make them?" because something has to, and it's udev's purpose to do that. "relationship between udev and device nodes" udev creates them, as you mention. The rest is really just replications of the first two questions, and these are already duplicates of your first question, which I answered – but you never commented under that answer to explain what you didn't understand about it. So, I'll not be giving the same answer again.

Comment: And the fact that the system doesn't let you post shorter question is not something to be circumvented by babbling, but by explaining what your current state of research and understanding it. It can't be "I don't understand anything", because you got an answer to your previous question, but didn't ask for clarification on that, so you must have understood it.

Comment: Can you suggest how you plan to interact with the device if the device node do not exist? You cannot mount it, you cannot dd/cat/write/read it, etc..